# How to change behaviour of isinstance in python

Tags: python, dataset, isinstance

I am working with a large simulation code and am having a hard time executing some iteration. I have imported data of size 262144 from a text file and reshaped into a (64,64,64) set as such

```
    filename = path + 'density'
    file = open(filename, mode='rb')
    bin_array = array.array('f')
    bin_array.fromfile(file, 64 * 64 * 64)
    rho = np.reshape(bin_array, (64,64,64))
```

This is then stored in self.data as:

```
     self.data = [rho]
```

and accessed using self.data[0][x,y,z]. According to the manual for the code I'm working with, each value in rho needs to be a float of 4 bytes. Now when I run other working examples (call the data for this 'good_data'), the data used gives the following output for isinstance:

```
    isinstance(good_data, float) 
    >> True
```

Now when I use isinstance on rho, it returns false and I believe this is whats giving me problems. Can anyone tell me how I can have my data return true for isinstance? Essentially what I want is

```
    isinstance(rho[x,y,z], float)
    >> True
```

When I check the dtype it returns float32 but returns false for isinstance.
Thank you all!

Comment: Each *value* is a `float`, that however does not make `rho` itself a `float`, since it is an array of floats.

Comment: how do you suggest I convert rho into a float

Comment: A `float` is a single floating-point number. You can't make an array of floats into a single float, or it ceases to be an array. You say that in the documentation, "each value in rho needs to be a float", so it is explicitly asking for an array of floats, not a single float.

Comment: Is there a way for me to put a value of rho into isintance and return true for float? Because when I check dtype it says float32 but when i use isinstance it returns false

Comment: This is sounding like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a specific reason you need the built-in `isinstance()` function to return the wrong type? Or are you open to solutions such as `isinstance(rho[0,0,0], float)` or `if rho.dtype==float32: return True`?

Comment: in a nutshell my problem is I am getting a TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable error. This error comes from another portion of the simulation code trying to access rho. I don't understand why I get this error as I am no python expert, but I noticed that if I am using the codes built in example, the data type returns true for isinstance and so I feel like that should fix things.